# Is there any way to do processing after GCP dataflow has completed the job using apache beam?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there any way to do post processing after the GCP dataflow status is done/completed.
I have process where dataflow reads a file from GCP storage in batches and does some external api calls for transformation and writes back to another file.
I need to do some extra processing after all the batches are transformed/processed.
Is there any way to do that ?
I am using Apache Beam and template to run GCP datatflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are two options to mention:

1. You can use Cloud Composer to orchestrate a Dataflow job with other actions before and after. See [this article](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-dataflow-template-operator).
2. If you launch your job via code, you can call `PipelineResult.waitUntilFinish()` and then run additional code afterwards.